# How to reliably guess the encoding between MacRoman, CP1252, Latin1, UTF-8, and ASCII

Tags: character-encoding

At work it seems like no week ever passes without some encoding-related conniption, calamity, or catastrophe.  The problem usually derives from programmers who think they can reliably process a “text” file without specifying the encoding.  But you can't.

So it's been decided to henceforth forbid files from ever having names that end in `*.txt` or `*.text`.  The thinking is that those extensions mislead the casual programmer into a dull complacency regarding encodings, and this leads to improper handling.  It would almost be better to have no
extension at all, because at least then you *know* that you don’t know what you’ve got.

However, we aren’t goint to go that far.  Instead you will be expected to use a filename that ends in the encoding.  So for text files, for example, these would be something like `README.ascii`, `README.latin1`, `README.utf8`, etc.

For files that demand a particular extension, if one can specify the encoding inside the file itself, such as in Perl or Python, then you shall do that.  For files like Java source where no such facility exists internal to the file, you will put the encoding before the extension, such as `SomeClass-utf8.java`.

For output, UTF-8 is to be **strongly** preferred.

But for input, we need to figure out how to deal with the thousands of files in our codebase named `*.txt`.  We want to rename all of them to fit into our new standard.  But we can’t possibly eyeball them all.  So we need a library or program that actually works.

These are variously in ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, Microsoft CP1252, or Apple MacRoman.  Although we're know we can tell if something is ASCII, and we stand a good change of knowing if something is probably UTF-8, we’re stumped about the 8-bit encodings.  Because we’re running in a mixed Unix environment (Solaris, Linux, Darwin) with most desktops being Macs, we have quite a few annoying MacRoman files.  And these especially are a problem.

For some time now I’ve been looking for a way to programmatically determine which of

1. ASCII
2. ISO-8859-1
3. CP1252
4. MacRoman
5. UTF-8

a file is in, and I haven’t found a program or library that can reliably distinguish between those the three different 8-bit encodings.  We probably have over a thousand MacRoman files alone, so whatever charset detector we use has to be able to sniff those out.  Nothing I’ve looked at can manage the trick.  I had big hopes for the [ICU charset detector library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection#TOC-CharsetDetector), but it cannot handle MacRoman.  I’ve also looked at modules to do the same sort of thing in both Perl and Python, but again and again it’s always the same story: no support for detecting MacRoman.

What I am therefore looking for is an existing library or program that reliably determines which of those five encodings a file is in—and preferably more than that.  In particular it has to distinguish between the three 3-bit encoding I’ve cited, **especially MacRoman**.  The files are more than 99% English language text; there are a few in other languages, but not many.

If it’s library code, our language preference is for it to be in Perl, C, Java, or Python, and in that order.  If it’s just a program, then we don’t really care what language it’s in so long as it comes in full source, runs on Unix, and is fully unencumbered.

Has anyone else had this problem of a zillion legacy text files randomly encoded?  If so, how did you attempt to solve it, and how successful were you?  This is the most important aspect of my question, but I’m also interested in whether you think encouraging programmers to name (or rename) their files with the actual encoding those files are in will help us avoid the problem in the future.   Has anyone ever tried to enforce this on an institutional basis, and if so, was *that* successful or not, and why?

And yes, I fully understand why one cannot guarantee a definite answer given the nature of the problem.   This is especially the case with small files, where you don’t have enough data to go on. Fortunately, our files are seldom small. Apart from the random `README` file, most are in the size range of 50k to 250k, and many are larger.  Anything more than a few K in size is guaranteed to be in English.

The problem domain is biomedical text mining, so we sometimes deal with extensive and extremely large corpora, like all of PubMedCentral’s Open Access respository.   A rather huge file is the BioThesaurus 6.0, at 5.7 gigabytes. This file is especially annoying because it is *almost* all UTF-8.  However, some numbskull went and stuck a few lines in it that are in some 8-bit encoding—Microsoft CP1252, I believe.  It takes quite a while before you trip on that one. :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255305/how-to-determine-encoding-table-of-a-text-file/4255439#4255439 for a solution

Answer (score 88, accepted):

First, the easy cases:

### ASCII

If your data contains no bytes above 0x7F, then it's ASCII.  (Or a 7-bit ISO646 encoding, but those are very obsolete.)

### UTF-8

If your data validates as UTF-8, then you can safely assume it *is* UTF-8.  Due to UTF-8's strict validation rules, false positives are extremely rare.

### ISO-8859-1 vs. windows-1252

The only difference between these two encodings is that ISO-8859-1 has the C1 control characters where windows-1252 has the printable characters €‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ.  I've seen plenty of files that use curly quotes or dashes, but none that use C1 control characters.  So don't even bother with them, or ISO-8859-1, just detect windows-1252 instead.

That now leaves you with only one question.

## How do you distinguish MacRoman from cp1252?

This is a lot trickier.

### Undefined characters

The bytes 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x9D are not used in windows-1252.  If they occur, then assume the data is MacRoman.

### Identical characters

The bytes 0xA2 (¢), 0xA3 (£), 0xA9 (©), 0xB1 (±), 0xB5 (µ) happen to be the same in both encodings.  If these are the only non-ASCII bytes, then it doesn't matter whether you choose MacRoman or cp1252.

### Statistical approach

Count character (NOT byte!) frequencies in the data you know to be UTF-8.  Determine the most frequent characters.  Then use this data to determine whether the cp1252 or MacRoman characters are more common.

For example, in a search I just performed on 100 random English Wikipedia articles, the most common non-ASCII characters are `·•–é°®’èö—`.  Based on this fact,

- The bytes 0x92, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0xAE, 0xB0, 0xB7, 0xE8, 0xE9, or 0xF6 suggest windows-1252.
- The bytes 0x8E, 0x8F, 0x9A, 0xA1, 0xA5, 0xA8, 0xD0, 0xD1, 0xD5, or 0xE1 suggest MacRoman.

Count up the cp1252-suggesting bytes and the MacRoman-suggesting bytes, and go with whichever is greatest.

Comment: I’ve accepted your answer because no better one has presented itself, and you did a good job writing up the very issues that I had been tinkering with. I indeed have programs to sniff out those bytes, although you have about twice the number that I had myself come up with.

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this. Turns out Wikipedia is not good training data. From 1k random en.wikipedia articles, not counting the LANGUAGES section, I got 50k unASCII codepoints, but the distribution is not credible: middle dot and bullet are too high, &c&c&c. So I used the all-UTF8 PubMed Open Access corpus, mining +14M unASCII codepoints. I use these to build a relative-frequency model of all the 8-bit encodings, fancier than yours but based on that idea. This proves ***highly predictive*** of the encoding for biomedical texts, the target domain. I should publish this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't still have any MacRoman files, but would not the use of CR as line delimiters provide a useful test. This would work for older versions of Mac OS, although i do not know about OS9.

Comment: Hi, its never too late to answer. After reading this answer I extended the ruby charlotte gem. Its now detecting pretty well the above formats. I appended a new answer with that main code to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276978/2731103

Comment: If it's only 0x00 to 0x7f, then it could be any encoding - but it doesn't really matter because everything will be decoded equally no matter what encoding you assume.

Answer (score 10):

[Mozilla nsUniversalDetector](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html) (Perl bindings: [Encode::Detect](http://p3rl.org/Encode::Detect)/[Encode::Detect::Detector](http://p3rl.org/Encode::Detect::Detector)) is millionfold proven.

Comment: More documentation is found here: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/detectorsrc.html, from there, it suggest that if you dig into the docs you can find the supported charsets

Comment: @Joel: I've dug into the source. It was a rhetorical question. `x-mac-cyrillic` is supported, `x-mac-hebrew` is discussed at length in the comments, `x-mac-anything-else` doesn't get a mention.

Comment: @John Machin: odd that cyrillic and hebrew get a nod, but nothing else. I was only tossing in another documentation source, I hadn't read further, thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 7):

My attempt at such a heuristic (assuming that you've ruled out ASCII and UTF-8):

- If 0x7f to 0x9f don't appear at all, it's probably ISO-8859-1, because those are very rarely used control codes.
- If 0x91 through 0x94 appear at lot, it's probably Windows-1252, because those are the "smart quotes", by far the most likely characters in that range to be used in English text. To be more certain, you could look for pairs.
- Otherwise, it's MacRoman, especially if you see a lot of 0xd2 through 0xd5 (that's where the typographic quotes are in MacRoman).

Side note:

> For files like Java source where no
>   such facility exists internal to the
>   file, you will put the encoding before
>   the extension, such as
>   SomeClass-utf8.java

**Do not do this!!**

The Java compiler expects file names to match class names, so renaming the files will render the source code uncompilable. The correct thing would be to guess the encoding, then use the [`native2ascii`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) tool to convert all non-ASCII characters to [Unicode escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Syntax/Unicode_Escape_Sequences).

Comment: Stoopid kompilor!  No, we cannot tell people they can only use ASCII; this isn’t the 1960s any more. It wouldn’t be a problem if there were an @encoding annotation so that the fact the source is in a particular encoding were not forced to be stored external to the source code, a really idiotic shortcoming of Java’s that neither Perl nor Python suffers from. It should be in the source.  That isn’t our main problem though; it’s the 1000s of `*.text` files.

Comment: @tchrist: It would actually not be all that hard to write your own annotation processor to support such an annotation. Still an embarassing oversight not to have it in the standard API.

Comment: Even if Java did support @encoding, that wouldn't ensure the encoding declaration being *correct*.

Comment: @dan04: You can say the same about the encoding declaration in XML, HTML or anywhere else. But just as with those examples, if it were defined in the Standard API, most tools that work with source code (especially editors and IDEs) would support it, which would pretty reliably prevent people from *accidentally* creating files whose contents' encoding does not match the declartion.

Comment: "The Java compiler expects file names to match class names."  This rule only applies if the file defines a top-level public class.

Answer (score 6):

"Perl, C, Java, or Python, and in that order": interesting attitude :-)

"we stand a good change of knowing if something is probably UTF-8": Actually the chance that a file containing meaningful text encoded in some other charset that uses high-bit-set bytes will decode successfully as UTF-8 is vanishingly small.

UTF-8 strategies (in least preferred language):

```
# 100% Unicode-standard-compliant UTF-8
def utf8_strict(text):
    try:
        text.decode('utf8')
        return True
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return False

# looking for almost all UTF-8 with some junk
def utf8_replace(text):
    utext = text.decode('utf8', 'replace')
    dodgy_count = utext.count(u'\uFFFD') 
    return dodgy_count, utext
    # further action depends on how large dodgy_count / float(len(utext)) is

# checking for UTF-8 structure but non-compliant
# e.g. encoded surrogates, not minimal length, more than 4 bytes:
# Can be done with a regex, if you need it
```

Once you've decided that it's neither ASCII nor UTF-8:

The Mozilla-origin charset detectors that I'm aware of don't support MacRoman and in any case don't do a good job on 8-bit charsets especially with English because AFAICT they depend on checking whether the decoding makes sense in the given language, ignoring the punctuation characters, and based on a wide selection of documents in that language.

As others have remarked, you really only have the high-bit-set punctuation characters available to distinguish between cp1252 and macroman. I'd suggest training a Mozilla-type model on your own documents, not Shakespeare or Hansard or the KJV Bible, and taking all 256 bytes into account. I presume that your files have no markup (HTML, XML, etc) in them -- that would distort the probabilities something shocking.

You've mentioned files that are mostly UTF-8 but fail to decode. You should also be very suspicious of:

(1) files that are allegedly encoded in ISO-8859-1 but contain "control characters" in the range 0x80 to 0x9F inclusive ... this is so prevalent that the draft HTML5 standard says to decode *ALL* HTML streams declared as ISO-8859-1 using cp1252.

(2) files that decode OK as UTF-8 but the resultant Unicode contains "control characters" in the range U+0080 to U+009F inclusive ... this can result from transcoding cp1252 / cp850 (seen it happen!) / etc files from "ISO-8859-1" to UTF-8.

Background: I have a wet-Sunday-afternoon project to create a Python-based charset detector that's file-oriented (instead of web-oriented) and works well with 8-bit character sets including `legacy ** n` ones like cp850 and cp437. It's nowhere near prime time yet. I'm interested in training files; are your ISO-8859-1 / cp1252 / MacRoman files as equally "unencumbered" as you expect anyone's code solution to be?

Comment: the reason for the language ordering is the environment. Most of our major applications tend to be in java and the minor utilities and some applications are in perl. We have a little bit of code here and there that is in python. I'm mostly a C and perl programmer, at least by first choice, so I was looking either for a java solution to plug into our app library, or a perl library for the same. If C, I could build an XS glue layer to connect it to the perl interface, but I haven’t ever done that in python before.

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered, there is no perfect way to solve this problem, because without the implicit knowledge about which encoding a file uses, all 8-bit encodings are exactly the same: A collection of bytes. All bytes are valid for all 8-bit encodings.

The best you can hope for, is some sort of algorithm that analyzes the bytes, and based on probabilities of a certain byte being used in a certain language with a certain encoding will guess at what encoding the files uses. But that has to know which language the file uses, and becomes completely useless when you have files with mixed encodings.

On the upside, if you know that the text in a file is written in English, then the you're unlikely to notice any difference whichever encoding you decide to use for that file, as the differences between all the mentioned encodings are all localized in the parts of the encodings that specify characters not normally used in the English language. You might have some troubles where the text uses special formatting, or special versions of punctuation (CP1252 has several versions of the quote characters for instance), but for the gist of the text there will probably be no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you can detect every encoding EXCEPT for macroman, than it would be logical to assume that the ones that can't be deciphered are in macroman. In other words, just make a list of files that couldn't be processed and handle those as if they were macroman.

Another way to sort these files would be to make a server based program that allows users to decide which encoding isn't garbled. Of course, it would be within the company, but with 100 employees doing a few each day, you'll have thousands of files done in no time.

Finally, wouldn't it be better to just convert all existing files to a single format, and require that new files be in that format.

Comment: Funny! When I first read this comment after being interrupted for 30 minutes, I read "macroman" as "macro man" and didn't make the connection with MacRoman until I'd run a search for that string to see whether the OP had mentioned it

Comment: +1 this answer is kind of interesting. not sure if it's a good or bad idea. can anyone think of an existing encoding that might also go undetected? is there likely to be one in the future?

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone else had this problem of a zillion legacy text files randomly encoded? If so, how did you attempt to solve it, and how successful were you?

I am currently writing a program that translates files into XML. It has to autodetect the type of each file, which is a superset of the problem of determining the encoding of a text file. For determining the encoding I am using a Bayesian approach. That is, my classification code computes a probability (likelihood) that a text file has a particular encoding for all the encodings it understands. The program then selects the most probable decoder. The Bayesian approach works like this for each encoding.

1. Set the initial (*prior*) probability that the file is in the encoding, based on the frequencies of each encoding.
2. Examine each byte in turn in the file. Look-up the byte value to determine the correlation between that byte value being present and a file actually being in that encoding. Use that correlation to compute a new (*posterior*) probability  that the file is in the encoding. If you have more bytes to examine, use the posterior probability of that byte as the prior probability when you examine the next byte.
3. When you get to the end of the file (I actually look at only the first 1024 bytes), the proability you have is the probability that the file is in the encoding.

It transpires that Bayes' theorem becomes *very* easy to do if instead of computing probabilities, you compute *information content*, which is the logarithm of the *odds*: `info = log(p / (1.0 - p))`.

You will have to compute the initail priori probability, and the correlations, by examining a corpus of files that you have manually classified.

Answer (score 1):

Getting leaded by the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200765/2731103 I could improve the ruby gem "charlotte" to identify the requested encodings mostly correct.

We use that on productive environments for detecting CSV file encodings before import

That's the reasonable parts (Ruby)

```rb
UTF8HASBOM = /^\xEF\xBB\xBF/n      #  [239, 187, 191]
UTF32LEBOM = /^\xFF\xFE\x00\x00/n  # [255, 254, 0, 0]
UTF32BEBOM = /^\x00\x00\xFE\xFF/n  # [0, 0, 254, 255]

UTF16LEBOM = /^\xFF\xFE/n                # [255, 254]
UTF16BEBOM = /^\xFE\xFF/n                # [254, 255]

NOTIN1BYTE = /[\x00-\x06\x0B\x0E-\x1A\x1C-\x1F\x7F]/n
NOTISO8859 = /[\x00-\x06\x0B\x0E-\x1A\x1C-\x1F\x7F\x80-\x84\x86-\x9F]/n

# Information to identify MacRoman
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/
NOTINCP1252 = /[\x81\x8D\x8F\x90\x9D]/n
CP1252CHARS = /[\x92\x95\x96\x97\xAE\xB0\xB7\xE8\xE9\xF6]/n
MCROMNCHARS = /[\x8E\x8F\x9A\xA1\xA5\xA8\xD0\xD1\xD5\xE1]/n
```

```rb
detect.force_encoding('BINARY') # Needed to prevent non-matching regex charset.
sample = detect[0..19]     # Keep sample string under 23 bytes.
detect.sub!(UTF8HASBOM, '') if sample[UTF8HASBOM] # Strip any UTF-8 BOM.

# See: http://www.daniellesucher.com/2013/07/23/ruby-case-versus-if/
if    sample.ascii_only? && detect.force_encoding('UTF-8').valid_encoding?

elsif sample[UTF32LEBOM] && detect.force_encoding('UTF-32LE').valid_encoding?
elsif sample[UTF32BEBOM] && detect.force_encoding('UTF-32BE').valid_encoding?
elsif sample[UTF16LEBOM] && detect.force_encoding('UTF-16LE').valid_encoding?
elsif sample[UTF16BEBOM] && detect.force_encoding('UTF-16BE').valid_encoding?

elsif detect.force_encoding('UTF-8').valid_encoding?

elsif detect.force_encoding('BINARY')[NOTISO8859].nil?
  detect.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')

elsif detect.force_encoding('BINARY')[NOTIN1BYTE].nil?

  if  detect.force_encoding('BINARY')[NOTINCP1252].nil? &&
            detect.force_encoding('BINARY').scan(MCROMNCHARS).length < detect.force_encoding('BINARY').scan(CP1252CHARS).length

      detect.force_encoding('Windows-1252')
  else
      detect.force_encoding('MacRoman')
  end

else  detect.force_encoding('BINARY')
end
```