# How to determine encoding table of a text file

Tags: text, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have `.txt` and `.java` files and I don't know how to determine the encoding table of the files (Unicode, UTF-8, ISO-8525, …). Does there exist any program to determine the file encoding or to see the encoding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reliably guess the encoding between MacRoman, CP1252, Latin1, UTF-8, and ASCII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/how-to-reliably-guess-the-encoding-between-macroman-cp1252-latin1-utf-8-and-a)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you're on Linux, try `file -i filename.txt`.

```
$ file -i vol34.tex 
vol34.tex: text/x-tex; charset=us-ascii
```

For reference, here is my environment:

```
$ which file
/usr/bin/file
$ file --version
file-5.09
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

Some `file` versions (e.g. file-5.04 on OS X/macOS) have slightly different command-line switches:

```
$ file -I vol34.tex 
vol34.tex: text/x-tex; charset=us-ascii
$ file --mime vol34.tex
vol34.tex: text/x-tex; charset=us-ascii
```

Also, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file).

Answer (score 31):

Open the file with Notepad++ and will see on the right down corner the encoding table name. And in the menu encoding you can change the encoding table and save the file.

Answer (score 13):

You can't reliably detect the encoding from a textfile - what you can do is make an 
educated guess by searching for a non-ascii char and trying to determine if it is a 
unicode combination that makes sens in the languages you are parsing.

Answer (score 4):

See this [question and the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/how-to-reliably-guess-the-encoding-between-macroman-cp1252-latin1-utf-8-and-a). There’s no sure-fire way of doing it. At most, you can rule things out.  The UTF encodings you’re unlikely to get false positives on, but the 8-bit encodings are tough, especially if you don’t know the starting language. No tool out there currently handles all the common 8-bit encodings from Macs, Windows, Unix, but the selected answer provides an algorithmic approach that should work adequately for a certain subset of encodings.

Answer (score 1):

In a text file *there is no header that saves the encoding* or so. You can try the linux/unix command `find` which tries to guess the encoding:

```
file -i unreadablefile.txt
```

or on some systems

```
file -I unreadablefile.txt
```

But that often gives you `text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1` although the file is unreadable (cryptic glyphs).

This is what I did to find the correct file encoding for an unreadable file and then translate it to utf8 was, after installing `iconv`. First I tried all encodings, displaying (`grep`) a line that contained the word *www.* (a website address):

```
for ENCODING in $(iconv -l); do echo -n "$ENCODING "; iconv -f $ENCODING -t utf-8 unreadablefile.txt 2>/dev/null| grep 'www'; done | less
```

This last commandline shows the the tested file encoding and then the translated/transcoded line.

There were some lines which showed readable and consistent (one language at a time) results. I tried manually some of them, for example:

```
ENCODING=WINDOWS-936; iconv -f $ENCODING -t utf-8 unreadablefile.txt -o test_with_${ENCODING}.txt
```

In my case it was a chinese windows encoding, which is now readable (if you know chinese).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python, the [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package is a good option, for example

```
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

files = ['a-1.txt','a-2.txt']

detector = UniversalDetector()
for filename in files:
    print(filename.ljust(20), end='')
    detector.reset()
    for line in open(filename, 'rb'):
        detector.feed(line)
        if detector.done: break
    detector.close()
    print(detector.result)
```

gives me as a result:

```
a-1.txt   {'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.7255358182877111, 'language': ''}
a-2.txt   {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does there exist any program to determine the file encoding or to see the encoding?

This question is 10 years old as I write this, and the answer is still, "No" - at least not reliably. There's not been much improvement unfortunately. My recent experience suggests the `file -I` command is very much *"[hit-or-miss](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hit-or-miss)"*. For example, when checking a ***text file*** on macOS 10.15.6:

```
% file -i somefile.asc
somefile.asc: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

`somefile.asc` was a text file. All charcters in it were encoded in **UTF-16 Little Endian**. How did I know this? I used `BBedit` - a competent text editor. Determining the encoding used in a file is certainly a tough problem, but...?