# Python read csv with Hebrew header

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, hebrew

I tried to use `dataset=pandas.read_csv('filename')` to make a framework. But somehow I can't do it because one of the column headers is written in Hebrew.

I checked, and it is possible for a DataFrame to have a Hebrew word as column header.
 `dataset.columns = ['שלום', 'b','c','d','e']` but I want to import the data itself from the csv containing the Hebrew word, which I can't.

I get this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte`.

How can I import a dataset to datadrame with the column header?

Answer (score 9):

I used:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-8")
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings for encodings

Answer (score 4):

Your file is not in `utf-8` encoding.

Most likely in ASCII with `Hebrew codepage`.

`0xf9` in Hebrew codepage matches the first (last) character you show in your header example.

You'll have to use the [`encoding:`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter with [the correct codepage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Answer (score 2):

As for how to check your encoding, there's a simple trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37177384/8874696), might be of use:

> You can just open the file using notepad and then goto File -> Save As. Next to the Save button there will be an encoding drop down and the file's current encoding will be selected there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which worked for me:

```
 import pandas as pd

 f = open('your_file_path', encoding='iso8859-8',errors='replace')
 data = pd.read_csv(f, sep='|')
```

The sep can be different for your document. The main thing here is to open at first with iso8859-8 encoding, and only after put this object into 'read csv with pandas'.