# Pandas: read_csv incorrectly producing a dataframe of NaNs with first element as special character

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file using the following code:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    encoding=f.encoding

test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding = encoding, sep='|', dtype=str, header=None)
test.head()
```

The output is a dataframe of NaN values, except for the first element in the dataframe which looks like something in cyrillic/greek.

The above encoding is 'cp1252'. I tried 'ISO-8859-1' but got the same result. I also tried 'utf-8' but got the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I even tried using python engine and that produceed the following error.

```
ParserError: NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass in engine='c' instead
```

By the way, I have no issues loading the file in Excel using text to columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv file has a byte order mark (BOM). The answer to my question may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967744/python-pandas-how-to-read-a-csv-in-cp1252-with-a-first-row-to-delete)