# How do I resolve UTF-8 encoding error with read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I am doing an assignment for my data analytics class and when I attempt to read the csv file for the "main_genre_df" it is giving me an encoding error? I have looked online and it told me to specify the encoding but I don't know what encoding to use.
I could definitely use some help.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Data anal\Assignment 2\template.py", line 124, in <module>
      main()
    File "Data anal\Assignment 2\template.py", line 119, in main
      task5()
    File "Data anal\Assignment 2\template.py", line 81, in task5
      main_genre_df = pd.read_csv('main_genre.csv')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 1524: invalid start byte
```

And here is the method I am creating:

```
def task5():

    main_genre_df = pd.read_csv('main_genre.csv')
    movies_df = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')

    for genre in main_genre_df.columns:
        terms = main_genre_df[genre].str.lower().tolist()
        selected_movies = movies_df[movies_df['Synopsis'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(terms))]
        most_frequent_genre = selected_movies['main_Genre'].value_counts().idxmax()
        print(f"{genre}: {most_frequent_genre}")
```

I am expecting it to return the most frequent genre for each main genre, like this:

fantasy: fantasy,
romance: romance,
drama: sport,
Crime: music,
mystery: mystery,
comedy: romance,
documentary: documentary,
sci-fi: animation,

Comment: Typically I would open the csv file in a text editor with the idea that if it works it will also be able to show the encoding (typically, a good text editor often indicates the encoding in a status bar).

Comment: But you might have a binary file, not a csv file ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648848/20430449