# Read a CSV without knowing Unicode

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode

I tried to read the CSV (stored in my OneDrive) all day long - with no success.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArV4HGOvFQJuhap7lf6ETfpcnLl6Og?e=7SEeL7

Best attempt until now: I got a dataframe with *one* column and the correct number of rows - but normally it should be around 20 columns. I found many interesting posts here. The best one was https://stackoverflow.com/a/75445718, which I implemented.

I changed the return line as follows:

```
    try:
        byte_size = int(os.path.getsize(path) * size)

        with open(path, "rb") as rawdata:
            result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(byte_size))

        return pd.read_csv(path, encoding=result["encoding"], header=1, sep='\t')

    except UnicodeError:
        return self.read_csv(path=path, size=size + 0.20)
```

I have no idea why it "works" (a bit) with \t... if I open the CSV in notepad there are `;` as separator. Notepad++ tells me it's "UTF-16 Little Endian", but it doesn't work (Pandas doesn't know this code).

In the end, I would try to read it line by line and build my own dataframe... but this would be the last move.

Comment: " if I open the csv in notepad there are ; as separator. notepad++ tells me, it's "UTF-16 Little Endian", but it doesnt work (pandas dont know this code)." what do you mean "this doesn't work"? What do you mean pandas doesn't know it? Did you try passing `encoding='utf_16_le'`? What happened? Please provide a [mcve], tell us *exactly* the errors you are encountering. Don't make us guess

Comment: `chardet` guesses at the correct encoding based on the distribution of byte values. If you look at how it populates `result['encoding']`, you'll see the correct argument to tell pandas that it's little-endian UTF-16.

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv(path, encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=";")`...

Comment: encoding='utf_16_le' worked! I tried 'utf-16-le'. omg.. I am so stupid. Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: The file you shared in the cloud is definitely latin-1 (ISO-88591-1) and separated w/semicolons. I have an answer below for that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply specifying the encoding ?

The header contains some [Latin-1](https://256stuff.com/gray/docs/latin.html) characters like the degree sign ([`°`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B0)) :

```
fp = r"Weathercloud fambon05 2023-12.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(fp, sep=";", encoding="latin-1") # or ansi
```

Output :

```
Datum (Europe/Berlin) Temperatur Innen (°C)  ... Solarstrahlung (W/m²) UV Index
     2023-12-01 00:00                  21,4  ...                     0     0.00
     2023-12-01 00:10                  21,4  ...                     0     0.00
     2023-12-01 00:20                  21,3  ...                     0     0.00
     2023-12-01 00:30                  21,4  ...                     0     0.00
     2023-12-01 00:40                  21,4  ...                     0     0.00
                  ...                   ...  ...                   ...      ...
     2023-12-31 23:10                  19,3  ...                   NaN      NaN
     2023-12-31 23:20                  19,4  ...                   NaN      NaN
     2023-12-31 23:30                  19,3  ...                   NaN      NaN
     2023-12-31 23:40                  19,2  ...                   NaN      NaN
     2023-12-31 23:50                  19,4  ...                   NaN      NaN

[4464 rows x 19 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your program that works for me:

```py
import chardet
import pandas as pd

csv_path = "input.csv"

with open(csv_path, "rb") as f:
    detected = chardet.detect(f.read(1024))
    enc_name = detected["encoding"]
    confidence = detected["confidence"]

print(f"detected encoding '{enc_name}' w/confidence {confidence:.1%}")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep=";", encoding=enc_name)

print(df)
```

and I get:

```
detected encoding 'ISO-8859-1' w/confidence 73.0%
     Datum (Europe/Berlin) Temperatur Innen (°C) Temperatur (°C)  ... Regenrate (mm/h)  Solarstrahlung (W/m²) UV Index
0         2023-12-01 00:00                  21,4              60  ...                0                      0      0.0
1         2023-12-01 00:10                  21,4              60  ...                0                      0      0.0
2         2023-12-01 00:20                  21,3              60  ...                0                      0      0.0
3         2023-12-01 00:30                  21,4              60  ...                0                      0      0.0
4         2023-12-01 00:40                  21,4              60  ...                0                      0      0.0
...                    ...                   ...             ...  ...              ...                    ...      ...
4459      2023-12-31 23:10                  19,3             NaN  ...              NaN                    NaN      NaN
4460      2023-12-31 23:20                  19,4             NaN  ...              NaN                    NaN      NaN
4461      2023-12-31 23:30                  19,3             NaN  ...              NaN                    NaN      NaN
4462      2023-12-31 23:40                  19,2             NaN  ...              NaN                    NaN      NaN
4463      2023-12-31 23:50                  19,4             NaN  ...              NaN                    NaN      NaN

[4464 rows x 19 columns]
```

The only structural difference I can see is that you were using tabs ('\t') as your seperator and not semicolons (';').  Other than that, it's pretty much what you shared.  I did opt to only read the first 1K to determine the encoding; in this case it reports the correct encoding with the same confidence (73%) whether reading the whole file (`f.read()`) or just the first 1K.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the `encoding` format (for instance `latin`) or if you don't know refers to the following encoding :

- Unicode (`UTF-8`): Reads the file in Unicode UTF-8 format.
- Unicode (`UTF-16`): Reads the file in Unicode UTF-16 format in the order (endism) of the operating system.
- Unicode (`UTF-16BE`): Reads the file in Unicode UTF-16 format in big endian order.
- Unicode (`UTF-16LE`): Reads the file in Unicode UTF-16 format in little endian order.

`utf-8` is used for decoding normal characters whereas `utf-16` is able to decode special characters

```py
# Read the CSV file using the appropriate encoding and separator
df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding="utf-16-le", delimiter="\t")
```