# Is there a way to remove special characters from a text file?

Tags: command-line, text-analysis

I'm attempting to do some basic text analysis from the command line, but whenever I try to run a command, I get the following: tr: Illegal byte sequence. I've narrowed the problem down to the special characters within the text (´, ˆ,¨, etc.) Is there something I can do to remove these special characters from the text? Can I use the command line? Or do I have to run a script?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141420/tr-complains-of-illegal-byte-sequence, I think your file is in the wrong encoding. On what OS are you? See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using macOS Sierra. I'll give the link you provided a look.

Comment: So if you really want to get rid of the non-ascii in your file, maybe `iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT` is what you are looking for. Or rather with something else in place of the `utf8`, depending on what's in your file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods.

Comment: And you can use `file -I` to guess the encoding of your file, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255305/how-to-determine-encoding-table-of-a-text-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are trying to process your text, but apparently you are trying to run `tr`, which gives you the error message `tr: Illegal byte sequence`. This happens when its input is not a byte sequence that corresponds to a valid UTF-8 encoding (not all byte sequences correspond to the UTF-8 encoding of a series of Unicode characters).

I do not know what kind of file you are trying to process, but in a MacOS X environment the command `file -I` might give you an idea of the encoding that is actually there.

If it is just a matter of recoding your file, then `iconv` is a useful program. You can use it to recode to UTF-8 encoding by using `iconv -f ... -t utf8` (where `...` is the encoding of your original file, run `iconv -l` for a list of encodings that are available that way).

Or if you really want to *remove* the special characters in your file (as you state in the title of your question), you can use `iconv -f ... -t ascii//TRANSLIT`. In this last case, the "special characters" will be approximated by normal ASCII characters.