# Boto3 : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 4084: invalid start byte

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem when I try to read a csv file :

```
# Load satisfaction table     
client = boto3.client('s3') #low-level functional API

resource = boto3.resource('s3') #high-level object-oriented API
my_bucket = resource.Bucket('bucket1') #subsitute this for your s3 bucket name. 
obj = client.get_object(Bucket='bucket1', Key='file.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), delimiter=',',engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
```

I get this error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 76: invalid start byte
```

Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: Use a different encoding? (the one that the *.csv* file has the text encoded with)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 35: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529507/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x96-in-position-35)

Comment: In my case the file was gzipped.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the problem:

On OSx, solved by deleting

```
.aws
```

folder under userprofile.
Seems like boto3 calls contents of .aws folder.

Comment: what is the reason for that?