# Split the particular value from .txt file and store on excel in python?

Tags: python, arrays, split, store

I have store bulk of **Temperature** and **Humidity** values in text file (`val.txt`). I need to store into the Excel sheet in separate columns.

Values in `val.txt` file:

```
SHT1 E:   T1:30.45°C    H1:59.14 %RH
SHT2 S:   T2:29.93°C    H2:67.38 %RH

SHT1 E:   T1:30.49°C    H1:58.87 %RH
SHT2 S:   T2:29.94°C    H2:67.22 %RH

SHT1 E:   T1:30.53°C    H1:58.69 %RH
SHT2 S:   T2:29.95°C    H2:67.22 %RH
//its continues same like this//
```

Expected output (in excel sheet):

```
Column1 (T1)     Column2 (H1)     Column3 (T2)     Column3 (H2)
30.45            59.14            29.93            67.38
30.49            58.87            29.94            67.22  
30.53            58.69            29.95            67.22
```

Comment: You should be able to do this using `pandas` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828811/how-to-convert-data-from-txt-files-to-excel-files-using-python/51828911)

Comment: It is great. But hear i have strings also. I need to grep float value only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this using `pandas`

```py
import itertools

import pandas as pd


def read_lines(file_object) -> list:
    return [
        parse_line(line) for line in file_object.readlines() if line.strip()
    ]


def parse_line(line: str) -> list:
    return [
        i.split(":")[-1].replace("°C", "").replace("%RH", "")
        for i in line.strip().split()
        if i.startswith(("T1", "T2", "H1", "H2"))
    ]


def flatten(parsed_lines: list) -> list:
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(parsed_lines))


def cut_into_pieces(flattened_lines: list, piece_size: int = 4) -> list:
    return [
        flattened_lines[i:i + piece_size] for i
        in range(0, len(flattened_lines), piece_size)
    ]


with open("your_text_data.txt") as data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        cut_into_pieces(flatten(read_lines(data))),
        columns=["T1", "H1", "T2", "H2"],
    )
    print(df)
    df.to_excel("your_table.xlsx", index=False)
```

Output:

```
      T1     H1     T2     H2
0  30.45  59.14  29.93  67.38
1  30.49  58.87  29.94  67.22
2  30.53  58.69  29.95  67.22
```

EDIT:

A much shorter approach with `regex`.

```
import re

import pandas as pd

with open("your_text_data.txt") as data_file:
    data_list = re.findall(r"\d\d\.\d\d", data_file.read())

pd.DataFrame(
    [data_list[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(data_list), 4)],
    columns=["T1", "H1", "T2", "H2"],
).to_excel(
    "your_table.xlsx",
    index=False,
)
```

This, however, doesn't print anything to `stdout` but results in the same structure of the Excel file as below.

As an `.xlsx` file:

[image]