# Unicode Error when trying to convert DBF to CSV

Tags: python, dbf

I'm in the process of converting really old data from years ago. The DBF won't convert into a CSV file, which I need because I will eventually use the data in SQL

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

My full code here:

```
import dbf
import simpledbf
from simpledbf import Dbf5


db = Dbf5('CREDIT.dbf')

db.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?  On the `to_csv` line?  It's possible the `simpledbf` module is very old (like Python 2), and isn't thinking about character sets.  You may need to modify the module.  dbf files are probably in CP-1252 (where 0xA5 is the Japanese yen symbol).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 35: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529507/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x96-in-position-35-invalid)

Comment: Please search for the error message online first! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It looks simpledbf accepts an encoding in its constructor.  Try:

```
db = Dbf5('CREDIT.dbf', codec="cp1252")
```