# Convert File with known encoding to UTF-8

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I need to convert text file to the String, which, finally, I should put as an input parameter (type InputStream) to IFile.create (Eclipse).
Looking for the example or how to do that but still can not figure out...need your help!

just for testing, I did try to convert original text file to UTF-8 encoded with this code

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

int ch;
while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
    buffer.append((char)ch);
}
in.close();


FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FilePath+".test.txt");
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
out.write(buffer.toString());
out.close();
```

but even thought the final *.test.txt file has UTF-8 encoding, the characters inside are corrupted.

Comment: BTW, are you writing an Eclipse plugin? Why are you using `IFile`?

Comment: Yes, this is in Eclipse plugin!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding of the `InputStreamReader` using the `Charset` parameter.

```
                                    // ↓ whatever the input's encoding is
Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, inputCharset));
```

This also works:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

---

See also:

- [`InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream%2C%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)
- [`Charset.forName(String charsetName)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Java: How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)
- [How to reliably guess the encoding between MacRoman, CP1252, Latin1, UTF-8, and ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/how-to-reliably-guess-the-encoding-between-macroman-cp1252-latin1-utf-8-and-a)
- [GuessEncoding](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GUESSENC/Home) - only works for UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, and UTF-32 ☹
- [ICU Charset Detector](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection#TOC-CharsetDetector)
- [cpdetector](http://cpdetector.sourceforge.net/), free java codepage detection
- [JCharDet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jchardet/) (Java port of Mozilla charset detector) <sub><sup>ironically, that page does not render the apostrophe in "Mozilla's" correctly</sup></sub>

SO search where I found all these links: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+detect+encoding

---

You can get the default charset - which is comes from the system the JVM is running on - at runtime via `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I'm getting Encoding from isr (isr.getEncoding()), doen't it already know what the encoding is?

Comment: Am I right that I have to do like: InputStreamReader isr1 = new InputStreamReader(fis); Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName(isr1.getEncoding()); InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, inputCharset)); ?

Comment: @Jack: nope, that's not how it works. There's really no way to **know** the encoding of an arbitrary chunk of text. If you haven't specified the encoding of the `InputStreamReader`, then the reader will have (therefore `isr.getEncoding()` will return) the **default** encoding.

Comment: I see, thank you! so, then, what is the best way to set Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"); without hardcoding it? Assume the text file is created on the same PC.

Comment: @Jack: if the text file is created on the same PC, **using the default charset**, then there should be no need to pass in a non-default charset.

Comment: @Jack: hey, I thought you said the file's encoding was known. What gives? :P

Comment: Agree, stated, but did not understand exactly what did it mean, sorry about that.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html, recommend to read, first of all to myself!

Comment: @Jack: so what was the solution you arrived at? Hardcoding the charset? I am curious.

Comment: @Matt: Probably will use icu4j to guess the encoding, since I really do not know what the encoding of the file is.