# How do I detect the encoding of some text?

Tags: encoding

How can I identify which format some text is encoded in, either ASCII, Unicode or UTF-8?

Comment: Actually, I'm quite sure it's EBCDIC.

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding.

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

There is no **guaranteed** way to detect the encoding of an arbitrary set of bytes.

---

### Long answer

- [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)
- [Java: How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)
- [How to reliably guess the encoding between MacRoman, CP1252, Latin1, UTF-8, and ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/how-to-reliably-guess-the-encoding-between-macroman-cp1252-latin1-utf-8-and-a)
- [GuessEncoding](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GUESSENC/Home) - only works for UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, and UTF-32 ☹
- [ICU Charset Detector](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection#TOC-CharsetDetector)
- [cpdetector](http://cpdetector.sourceforge.net/), free java codepage detection
- [JCharDet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jchardet/) (Java port of Mozilla charset detector) <sub><sup>ironically, that page does not render the apostrophe in "Mozilla's" correctly</sup></sub>

Ripped from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383504/convert-file-with-known-encoding-to-utf-8/4383520#4383520).

---

#### See also

- Typical suggestion: [Joel on Software
  The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- "Unicode" is **not** an encoding. [What's the difference between unicode and utf8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951722/whats-the-difference-between-unicode-and-utf8)
- **Also, you should probably read over** how to ask questions on Stack Overflow: [Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)