# How to distinguish the text file?

Tags: java, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect the encoding of some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475720/how-do-i-detect-the-encoding-of-some-text)

How to distinguish the unicode text file and others of a text file?

I am doing a bulk upload file using java.
first I write the inputs in excel file and then I do  save as Unicode text(.txt) file.
Then I will upload the Unicode text file, and read from my java class.

Here I have a problem.
I can distinguish the .txt files and other than text files. But how can i find a file whether it is Unicode text file or other text file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector;

public class TestDetector {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    String fileName = args[0];
    java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(fileName);

    // (1)
    UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

    // (2)
    int nread;
    while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
      detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
    }
    // (3)
    detector.dataEnd();

    // (4)
    String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
    if (encoding != null) {
      System.out.println("Detected encoding = " + encoding);
    } else {
      System.out.println("No encoding detected.");
    }

    // (5)
    detector.reset();
  }
}
```