# Ruby and encoding conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding

I'm importing a CSV file into Ruby (1.8.7). File.open('path/to/file.csv').read returns this in the console:

```
Stefan,Engstr\232m
```

The encoding is identified as iso-8859-2 by UniversalDetector (chardet gem).

```
UniversalDetector::chardet("Stefan,Engstr\232m")
=> {"confidence"=>0.626936305574385, "encoding"=>"ISO-8859-2"}
```

Trying to convert the string yields the following:

```
Iconv.conv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", "Stefan,Engstr\232m")
 => "Stefan,Engstrm"
```

whereas I would expect:

```
 => "Stefan,Engström"
```

- Could the string really be in some other encoding?
- I haven't seen the \232 syntax before, usually when strings are strangely encoded some weird character will show up instead, e.g. � or some chinese.

*Let me know if I should provide more information or elaborate on something.*

Comment: It does not look like it's `ISO-8859-2`. It would be `\246`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-2

Comment: @Kassym: It would be `\366` in ISO 8859-2, the `"\nnn"` notation uses octal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encoding is probably ["Macintosh Roman"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman), a couple other options would be ["Mac Central European"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Central_European_encoding) and ["Mac Icelandic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Icelandic_encoding). The `\nnn` notation uses octal so `\232` is 154 in decimal and character 154 is the lower case O-umlaut ("ö") that you're expecting in all three of those encodings; I don't see 154 in any of the Windows codepages or ISO 8859 character sets. I'd guess that Mac Roman is more common than the Icelandic or Central European encodings.

Try using `'MacRoman'` as your source encoding with Iconv:

```
>> Iconv.conv("UTF-8", "MacRoman", "Stefan,Engstr\232m")
=> "Stefan,Engström"
```

Comment: THANKS! I tried on the larger dataset and it worked well too. Now I just have to figure out how to detect the charset, since `UniversalDetector::chardet` couldn't do it correctly. You seem to know this area very well -- any thoughts?

Comment: After reading some more it seems to be tricky to distinguish Macroman. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/how-to-reliably-guess-the-encoding-between-macroman-cp1252-latin1-utf-8-and

Comment: @sandstrom: I don't know as much about encodings as tchrist (the author of the question you linked to). You'll notice that the three Mac encodings I listed overlap at ö so it could have been any of them, I guess MacRoman because that's more common than the others. This sort of thing usually boils down to a bunch of guess work based on empty slots in the various character tables, then you try it and change your guess if it breaks; dan04's answer is about as good as it gets. These days I do everything in UTF-8 and give people dirty looks if they try to use anything else :)

Comment: @sandstrom: The whole encoding issue is a nightmare and now you're starting to know why everything is moving towards UTF-8 for transport.