# Reading binary chars from a CSV file

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I have a strange problem: I have a CSV file that I read correctly with Notepad and MS Excel 2010.

I tried reading the rows of this file with this code:

```
BufferedReader source = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String currentRow = null;
while (null != (currentRow=source.readLine())){
    System.outprintln(currentRow)
}
```

When the program runs, I read just the binary characters and the length of the row is different from the reality (I expect 2000 chars for line and I found 55 chars or 1 char).

I work in Eclipse: If I open this CSV file as *text editor* I read strange chars, when I open it as *system editor* I read the correct value inside MS Excel.

The type of this file is *file with comma separated value of Microsoft Excel*: does this file have some binary chars?

I tried to use Apache POI (reading the file in CSV and in XLS) with this code:

```
public void displayFromExcel (String xlsPath){
    POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = null;
    try{
        fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (new FileInputStream (xlsPath));
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt (0);
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext ()){
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next ();
            System.out.println ("Row No.: " + row.getRowNum ());
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext ()){
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next ();

                System.out.println ("Cell No.: " + cell.getCellNum ());

                switch (cell.getCellType ()){
                    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
                        System.out.println ("Numeric value: " + cell.getNumericCellValue ());
                        break;
                    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :
                        HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();
                        System.out.println ("String value: " + richTextString.getString ());
                        break;
                    default :
                        System.out.println ("Type not supported.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

It isn't working, I receive this message to the console:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x003000310030FEFF, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlockReader.<init>(HeaderBlockReader.java:125)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:153)
```

When it runs this instruction:

```
POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (new FileInputStream (xlsPath));
```

I tried to use the library [datafile](http://datafile.sourceforge.net/) and the Java I/O (`DataInputstream`, etc.), but without success.

Any idea for the solution?

Comment: I'd guess your Excel file header is incorrect, based on the error you posted

Comment: 0xfffe is some unicode header prepended to some text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read this file with something more complicated than FileReader.  Check out [How to reliably guess encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/how-to-reliably-guess-the-encoding-between-macroman-cp1252-latin1-utf-8-and).  Then either find something that will read the file as encoded or write something that will filter out the junk.  I have found that if you treat a file as straight ASCII and throw out everything that's not a valid ASCII character, it will read a straight Unicode file (as well as a straight ASCII file) quite nicely.  If it's UTF-8 with Egyptian Hieroglyphics (and you want those Hieroglyphics) this doesn't work so well.

So first try to get "them" to give you a better file.  When that doesn't work, do some research in the java.io Javadoc and then do some programming.